# Cant log into, ping, or access my domain on my CentOS apache server

Tags: linux, centos, apache-http-server

I am sorry if this post is not clear, but I will do my best to explain my issue.  I am not fantastic at managing servers. I am more of a programmer than anything.

Anyway, I have a CentOS 7 server, and recently I tried to setup a mail server. I followed [this tutorial](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7), but I was unable to send email after. At this point I was still able to navigate to my domain. So I moved onto a different [tutorial here](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-centos-7-2-apache-mysql-php-pureftpd-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig). I reached the point where it said to do a reboot, and I was unable to log in using my normal root level account. Being with my root account having login disabled, the only way I was able to log in was by setting up a session in my hosting companies serial console.

I did run these commands:

```
sudo service httpd restart
sudo apachectl restart
sudo systemctl restart named.service
sudo systemctl start named
sudo systemctl enable named
```

But, they did not help.

I ran some commands I thought might be useful to you guys, and posted the output below.

```
# systemctl status firewalld
* firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)




# systemctl status httpd
* httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-10 17:06:05 EDT; 2h 4min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 2692 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2697 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 0; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           |-2697 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           `-2699 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Apr 10 17:06:05 server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 10 17:06:05 server systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.



# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination




# service sshd status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  sshd.service
* sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-04-10 13:12:14 EDT; 6h ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 1990 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           `-1990 /usr/sbin/sshd

Apr 10 13:12:14 server systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Apr 10 13:12:14 server sshd[1990]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 7822.
Apr 10 13:12:14 server sshd[1990]: Server listening on :: port 7822.
Apr 10 13:12:14 server systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.


# firewall-cmd --state
not running
```

Also, when I try to ping my server, I get a "request timed out".
When I try to log in with a normal user, on putty I get a "Network error: connection timed out", on another ssh client, I get "trying to authenticate, attempting 'password' authentication, authentication method 'password' failed".

I know this is nearly not enough information, but I will try to respond quickly. Let me know what you guys need to know and I will post it.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an IP address on your public interface?: `ip a`

Comment: Ip on public interface? not sure what you mean. I have a public IP I use for my DNS, nameservers, ssh.., and a separate IP i use for my serial console. Anyway, I resolved my issue.

Comment: The public interface is the interface that is supposed to have the public IP address.  The command `ip a` will tell you if that interface does indeed have your public IP address.

Comment: YES! I remember running that command and if I recall correctly, I do not think my IP was listed there. It is now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if this will be any use to anyone ever, but I thought I would post it anyway. I do not know exactly how I fixed the issue I was having, I changed a lot of settings, and restarted a lot of services, but I ended up realizing I did not have any internet connection my server at all. When I ran, `systemctl status network`, I noticed the error:

> failed to bring up/down networking: configure interface for a trunk
>   interfa

I ran the below commands:

```
service NetworkManager stop
service network restart
chkconfig NetworkManager off
chkconfig network on
```

and everything started working. I will now backup what I need and reinstall my OS to fix all other issues I know I created when investigating this. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.